# Why can't Laravel access .env vars after four seconds of load time

Tags: laravel, soap, environment-variables, php-7.4

My Laravel site uses SoapClient to access another site during an page load (with performs about 6 seconds of data processing before the soap call.)  I noticed sometimes the SoapClient switches to non-wsdl mode and the process errors out.  I discovered this was happening because the SoapClient was passed a NULL for its first constructor parameter (the URI of the WSDL file).  I though this was strange, because this value came directly from the .env file.  The site was having no trouble connecting to the database, so the .env file had to be working.  I set up a function that access .env variables repeatedly during the page load, using env(...).  During a Soap error, I discovered around the four second mark, the site lost access to the .env vars.  Before that point, the information was accessible. After that point, calls to env() returned NULL.  This may be related to other page request (possibly repeat calls to the same page, requesting the same process.)  Also, I just upgraded php to 7.4.13 (xampp with 64 bit thread support: php-7.4.13-Win32-vc15-x64.)  Has anyone seen this before, and has a way to address this issue?

EDIT ====

The SoapClient was created in a model, and the env() function was used to access the environmental vars.  I have learned that env() should not be used anywhere but config files.  This may explain my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen this problem. But an approach might be to load env variable into a config variable and use that instead. For example: create `extra.php` file in the config directory like this:

```php
<?php

return [
   'api_url' => env('API_URL'),
];
```

And use it like this:

```php
config('extra.api_url');
// Instead of env('API_URL')
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I went with a similar fix.  I loaded the .env file into $GLOBALS and accessed the vars from there.